# Cancel some file after git add

Tags: git

I commit the file with this.

```
git add .
git commit -am 'all'
```

However after this, I notices that I added the wrong file(too big).

So put this line in .gitignore

```
*.sql
```

However after this `*.sql` file is not removed from git.

And git push origin master takes too long time.

What can I fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is remove the file from index and then amend... that will remove the file from the revision (actually, you create a new revision)

```
git rm --cached the-sql-file # this _won´t_ remove the file from the working tree because of --cached
git commit --amend --no-edit
# now you can push
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git reset --soft HEAD~` to undo the last commit which hasn’t been pushed.

Be careful when putting *.sql in the .gitignore, that prevents you from committing sql files in the future and you might not want that

Comment: You can still forcibly add an ignored file or path with `git add -f`.

Comment: Even if this is a little bit longer recipe than mine, I think it is incomplete. You run `git reset --soft HEAD~`, then `git reset the-sql-file`, then `git commit -m "what you did in the revision"`, then you can push,

Comment: Thank you for your help. I simply `git rm test.sql` for this purpose. git reset is sometimes back all the file to the certain commit.